# What is the probability of getting STRAIGHT FLUSH in a $13$-card poker game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, poker

What is the probability of getting **STRAIGHT FLUSH** in a $13$-card poker game?

Here is my attempt:

A straight flush is *five cards in sequence and of the same suit*, **but 
not** ace king queen jack ten.

The required probability is
$$\dfrac{9 \cdot {4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 13}} = \dfrac{36}{635013559600} = \dfrac{9}{158753389900} \approx 5.66917028081678777\ldots \cdot{10}^{-11}.$$

My questions are:

> > **(1)** Is this probability computation correct?
> >
> > **(2)** If my computation is not correct, where is/are the error(s) and what hint can you give towards rectifying that error(s)?

Comment: As in the question about $4$ of a kind, the count is very much too small. It does not take into account the other $8$ cards.  Also, do two straight flush count? An Inclusion/Exclusion argument will work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes - two straight flushes will count.  Will an Inclusion/Exclusion argument similar to that in the question about $4$ of a kind, work?

Comment: There are $13 \choose 5$ ways to obtain a given straight flush among the 13 card hand, so multiply your result by that

Comment: btw, who plays 13-card poker?

Comment: @frogfanitw, 13-card poker is also known as [Chinese poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_poker).

Comment: @KashitokikuTeshikiari: It will work. The details are somewhat different, because straight flushes in the same suit can "interfere" with each other. By the way, two straight flushes are highly unlikely, so if you are willing to accept an excellent approximation, one can give a simple "almost correct" answer.

Comment: Yes, I will be willing to accept that "excellent approximation", @AndréNicolas.

Comment: I am hesitant to give anything but a complete answer.

Comment: Here is what I have (using Inclusion/Exclusion Principle):

The required probability is:
$$\dfrac{9\cdot{4 \choose 1}\cdot\left({48 \choose 8} - {43 \choose 5}\right)}{{52 \choose 13}} \approx 0.021337986.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the extra cards
It is 52 - 6 as you cannot have the card above of it makes a higher straight

This is for one

$$\frac {\binom{9}{1} \binom{4}{1} \binom{46}{8} } { \binom{52}{13} } = 0.01479 \approx 1 / 67.6$$

I think this is 2

$$\frac {\binom{9}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{40}{3} } { \binom{52}{13} } = 0.00000084 \approx 1 / 1190234$$